# md-option for selenium python, failed most of the time

Tags: python, selenium, dropdown

Hi I have the following code

```
<md-option ng-repeat="sector in allSector | orderBy:'name'" ng-value="{"id":239,"name":"MU-BHND-JC32-0033","regionInventory":{"id":18,"regionName":"Mumbai","zone":{"id":4,"name":"WEST","longitude":73.1812,"country":{"id":3,"name":"INDIA","countryCode":"IND"},"latitude":22.3072},"stateCode":"MU","latitute":19.076,"longitude":72.8777},"latitute":19.29117616,"longitude":73.04375901,"coordinates":null,"centroid":null}" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_982" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]" style>
```

Basically I want to select the element MU-BHND-JC32-0033 from the above code and click on it.

As id keeps on changing I am not open for going for id.

if someone can help me out in clicking using xpath and ng-value.

I tried the following but it failed

```
subRegOpt = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//md-option[@ng-value='MU-BHND-JC32-0033']")
sleep(5)
subRegOpt.click()
```

Comment: <md-option ng-repeat="sector in allSector | orderBy:'name'" ng-value="{"id":239,"name":"MU-BHND-JC32-0033","regionInventory":{"id":18,"regionName":"Mumbai","zone":{"id":4,"name":"WEST","longitude":73.1812,"country":{"id":3,"name":"INDIA","countryCode":"IND"},"latitude":22.3072},"stateCode":"MU","latitute":19.076,"longitude":72.8777},"latitute":19.29117616,"longitude":73.04375901,"coordinates":null,"centroid":null}" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_982" aria-checked="true" value="[object Object]" style>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace

```
subRegOpt = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//md-option[@ng-value='MU-BHND-JC32-0033']")
```

with

```
subRegOpt = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//md-option[contains(@ng-value, 'MU-BHND-JC32-0033')]")
```